# CMake - The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND

Tags: c++, cmake

I am using CMake on Linux Ubuntu.

Here is my Project Structure.

Root

- cmake
- Source
- - Common
- - Core
- - - AuthServer
- - - WorldServer

In Root `CMakeLists.txt` I have:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(Vibranium_Core)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

find_package(Boost 1.72.0)

if(NOT Boost_FOUND)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Could not find boost!")
endif()
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/")
find_package(MySQL REQUIRED)

include_directories(${MYSQL_INCLUDE_DIR})

add_subdirectory(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Source/Common)
add_subdirectory(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Source/Core/WorldServer)
add_subdirectory(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Source/Core/AuthServer)

set_target_properties(
        Common WorldServer AuthServer
        PROPERTIES
        ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/lib"
        LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/lib"
        RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin"
)
```

In `Source/Core/AuthServer/CMakeLists.txt` I have:

```
if(WIN32)
    if(MSVC)
        list(APPEND PRIVATE_SOURCES AuthServer.rc)
    endif()
endif()

add_executable(AuthServer AuthServer.cpp ${PRIVATE_SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(AuthServer LINK_PUBLIC Common)


if(NOT EXISTS ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/configs/)
    message(STATUS "Configs folder will be created: ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/configs")
    file(MAKE_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/configs/)
endif()

if(NOT EXISTS ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/configs/AuthServer.conf)
message(STATUS "New AuthServer Config file in will be installed in: ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/configs")
add_custom_command(
        TARGET AuthServer POST_BUILD
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/AuthServer.conf.dist
        ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/configs/)
endif()
```

In `Source/Core/WorldServer/CMakeLists.txt` I have:

```
if(WIN32)
    if(MSVC)
        list(APPEND PRIVATE_SOURCES WorldServer.rc)
    endif()
endif()

add_executable(WorldServer WorldServer.cpp ${PRIVATE_SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(WorldServer LINK_PUBLIC Common)

if(NOT EXISTS ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/configs/)
    message(STATUS "Configs folder will be created: ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/configs")
    file(MAKE_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/configs/)
endif()

if(NOT EXISTS ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/configs/WorldServer.conf)
message(STATUS "New WorldServer Config file in will be installed in: ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/configs")
add_custom_command(
TARGET WorldServer POST_BUILD
COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy
${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/WorldServer.conf.dist
${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/configs/)
endif()
```

In `cmake/FindMySQL.cmake` I have:

```
IF (MYSQL_INCLUDE_DIR)
  # Already in cache, be silent
  SET(MYSQL_FIND_QUIETLY TRUE)
ENDIF (MYSQL_INCLUDE_DIR)

FIND_PATH(MYSQL_INCLUDE_DIR mysql.h
        /usr/local/include/mysql
        /usr/include/mysql
        )

SET(MYSQL_NAMES mysqlclient mysqlclient_r)
FIND_LIBRARY(MYSQL_LIBRARY
        NAMES ${MYSQL_NAMES}
        PATHS /usr/lib /usr/local/lib
        PATH_SUFFIXES mysql
        )

IF (MYSQL_INCLUDE_DIR AND MYSQL_LIBRARY)
  SET(MYSQL_FOUND TRUE)
  SET( MYSQL_LIBRARIES ${MYSQL_LIBRARY} )
ELSE (MYSQL_INCLUDE_DIR AND MYSQL_LIBRARY)
  SET(MYSQL_FOUND FALSE)
  SET( MYSQL_LIBRARIES )
ENDIF (MYSQL_INCLUDE_DIR AND MYSQL_LIBRARY)

IF (MYSQL_FOUND)
  IF (NOT MYSQL_FIND_QUIETLY)
    MESSAGE(STATUS "Found MySQL: ${MYSQL_LIBRARY}")
  ENDIF (NOT MYSQL_FIND_QUIETLY)
ELSE (MYSQL_FOUND)
  IF (MYSQL_FIND_REQUIRED)
    MESSAGE(STATUS "Looked for MySQL libraries named ${MYSQL_NAMES}.")
    MESSAGE(FATAL_ERROR "Could NOT find MySQL library")
  ENDIF (MYSQL_FIND_REQUIRED)
ENDIF (MYSQL_FOUND)

MARK_AS_ADVANCED(
        MYSQL_LIBRARY
        MYSQL_INCLUDE_DIR
)
```

When I try to reload my Cmake configuration I have this error:

```
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
MYSQL_INCLUDE_DIR (ADVANCED)
   used as include directory in directory /home/venelin/Vibranium-Core
   used as include directory in directory /home/venelin/Vibranium-Core
   used as include directory in directory /home/venelin/Vibranium-Core/Source/Common
   used as include directory in directory /home/venelin/Vibranium-Core/Source/Common
   used as include directory in directory /home/venelin/Vibranium-Core/Source/Common
   used as include directory in directory /home/venelin/Vibranium-Core/Source/Core/WorldServer
   used as include directory in directory /home/venelin/Vibranium-Core/Source/Core/WorldServer
   used as include directory in directory /home/venelin/Vibranium-Core/Source/Core/WorldServer
   used as include directory in directory /home/venelin/Vibranium-Core/Source/Core/AuthServer
   used as include directory in directory /home/venelin/Vibranium-Core/Source/Core/AuthServer
   used as include directory in directory /home/venelin/Vibranium-Core/Source/Core/AuthServer

CMake Error in Source/Common/CMakeLists.txt:
  Found relative path while evaluating include directories of "Common":

    "MYSQL_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND"



CMake Error in Source/Common/CMakeLists.txt:
  Found relative path while evaluating include directories of "Common":

    "MYSQL_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND"



CMake Error in Source/Core/WorldServer/CMakeLists.txt:
  Found relative path while evaluating include directories of "WorldServer":

    "MYSQL_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND"



CMake Error in Source/Core/WorldServer/CMakeLists.txt:
  Found relative path while evaluating include directories of "WorldServer":

    "MYSQL_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND"



CMake Error in Source/Core/AuthServer/CMakeLists.txt:
  Found relative path while evaluating include directories of "AuthServer":

    "MYSQL_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND"



CMake Error in Source/Core/AuthServer/CMakeLists.txt:
  Found relative path while evaluating include directories of "AuthServer":

    "MYSQL_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND"



CMake Error in Source/Common/CMakeLists.txt:
  Found relative path while evaluating include directories of "Common":

    "MYSQL_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND"



CMake Error in Source/Common/CMakeLists.txt:
  Found relative path while evaluating include directories of "Common":

    "MYSQL_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND"



CMake Error in Source/Core/WorldServer/CMakeLists.txt:
  Found relative path while evaluating include directories of "WorldServer":

    "MYSQL_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND"



CMake Error in Source/Core/WorldServer/CMakeLists.txt:
  Found relative path while evaluating include directories of "WorldServer":

    "MYSQL_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND"



CMake Error in Source/Core/AuthServer/CMakeLists.txt:
  Found relative path while evaluating include directories of "AuthServer":

    "MYSQL_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND"



CMake Error in Source/Core/AuthServer/CMakeLists.txt:
  Found relative path while evaluating include directories of "AuthServer":

    "MYSQL_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND"
```

Why am I receiving this error and how can I fix it ?

Comment: Does `/usr/local/include/mysql` or `/usr/include/mysql` exist? If either of these folders exists is there a `mysql.h` file in it.

Comment: I think an [MCVE] could be a little bit shorter. So `Why am I receiving this error` because mysql package was not found. Does `/usr/include/mysql/mysql.h` exists? You most probably do not have mysql, so `how can I fix it ?` install mysql (development) files.

Comment: @drescherjm no in this dir `/usr/local/include/` I have only `boost` folder

Comment: What about `/usr/include/mysql`?

Comment: @drescherjm no there isn't such eitherl.

Comment: So there is your problem. You need to figure out where `mysql.h` exists and fix the path in the finder module you added. When you find the path you can add an additional entry in the FIND_PATH() command.

Comment: @drescherjm looks like I haven't done this `apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev` shame on me... Thank you mate.

Comment: If you have found a solution to the problem, please write an *answer* post explaining the fix so others can easily see how it was resolved.